# How to listen port if data sent via multiple clients in java socket

Tags: java, sockets

I have multiple clients that send data to same predefined IP address and port number. I am trying with **java socket**. I have one consumer code(server) that accepts data from multiple clients. But my consumer code is only listening to only first client data. And it ignores 2nd one.

server :-

```
public class consumer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverScoket=new ServerSocket(3333,10);        
        Socket socket=serverScoket.accept();  
        DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());     
        while(true){  
            String str="";
            str=din.readUTF();  
        if(str.length()>0)
        System.out.println("client says: "+str);  
        }  
    }
}
```

1st client :-

```
public class uploader1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Socket s=new Socket("localhost",3333);  
        DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());  
        int i = 0;
        while(i++<15){          
            Thread.sleep(1000); 
            dout.writeUTF("u1 "+i);  
            dout.flush();  
        }  

        dout.close();  
        s.close(); 
    }
}
```

2nd client :-

```
public class uploader2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Socket s=new Socket("localhost",3333);  
        DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());   
        int i = 0;
        while(i++<15){          
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            dout.writeUTF("u2 "+i);  
            dout.flush();   
        }         
        dout.close();  
        s.close(); 
    }
}
```

if the execution sequence is consumer,uploader1,uploader2 then it prints like this

```
client says: u1 1
client says: u1 2
client says: u1 3
client says: u1 4
client says: u1 5
client says: u1 6
client says: u1 7
client says: u1 8
client says: u1 9
client says: u1 10
client says: u1 11
client says: u1 12
client says: u1 13
client says: u1 14
client says: u1 15
```

Any idea whether I can achieve it through java socket programming or I need to find some other approach. Please suggest.

Comment: Because your server is only using the socket of the first connected client.
You'll need to store both accepted sockets into an array, then your while loop should account for both sockets.
Both will then block, so you'll need to either make the sockets non-blocking or use multithreading.

Comment: I am able to get response from server! In case of multiple clients as well. Its processing received data in sequence. What will happen in case of client count raised to thousands, server will get data on delayed time(since it is looking for same port) if yes how to handle it.

Comment: Via multithreading, as @TreytenCarey has already told you. See the Custom Networking chapter of the Java Tutorial.